# Dissertation court or seminar?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request, terminology

In my native language we say "dissertation court".
Can we say dissertation court in English? or we can just say dissertation seminar?

Comment: This is for defending a thesis for a PhD degree, right?

Comment: Are you asking about an oral examination, where a Master's or PhD student "defends" their thesis, and acknowledged experts "judge" whether the thesis is worthy of a degree?

Comment: For defending a dissertation, as we commonly say here. Can I just say "dissertation defense" then?

Comment: Yes, 'defense' is the stock term. My father called it "the faculty's last chance to harass the student".

Comment: We hear the phrases PhD/MPhil dissertation defense, dissertation defense, etc. in English, but not dissertation court .

Comment: Just for my curiosity, would you mind sharing what language calls it a dissertation court? As StoneyB says, *dissertation defense* is a superstandard term in the US; it would be odd to call it anything else.

Comment: We don't call it a dissertation court, but, now that you mention it, we totally should.

Answer (score 1):

To refer to the group of professors before which one defends their dissertation, one might use the term "***dissertation panel***" or "***dissertation committee***".

To refer to the event at which one defends their dissertation, one would use the term "***dissertation defense***".